# manylinux auditwheel installation errors

Tags: python, python-manylinux

I wanted to build auditwheel and run a command

```
auditwheel repair dist/*.whl
```

I get this two kind of errors on multiple versions of auditwheel

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'open_for_csv' from 'wheel.util' (/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.5/x64/lib/python3.7
```

and

```
auditwheel: error: cannot find the 'patchelf' tool, which is required
```

I've tried almost every version of auditwheel installation. could you help correct way to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct way to install `patchelf`:

```
wget http://nixos.org/releases/patchelf/patchelf-0.10/patchelf-0.10.tar.bz2
tar xf patchelf-0.10.tar.bz2
cd patchelf-0.10
./configure
make install
```

Comment: It is easier to install via apt-get, `sudo apt-get install patchelf`